# Difference in using TextBlock and FontIcon (when used outside AppBarButton)

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

For placing a font based icon in UI, what is the difference between

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
           Text="&#xE122;" />
```

and

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
          Glyph="&#xE122;" />
```

Which one should be preferred and why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is no best way. FontIcon can only Display one Icon. Textblock multiple.